# What is the most efficient way of computing similarity between two dictionnaries of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I want to compute accuracy using sets logic. I'll explain with an example:

For these two dictionnaries:

```
d1 = {1: {'hello', 'goodbye'}, 2:{'sayonnara'}, 3:{'origami'}}
d2 = {1: {'goodbye'}, 2:{'hola', 'bye'}, 3:{'bird','origami','giraffe'}}
```

I want to get this result:

```
{1: 0.5, 2: 0, 3: 0.3333333333333333}
```

I'm doing it this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
acc=defaultdict(list)
for (k,v1) in d1.items():
    for (k,v) in d2.items():
        nb=len(v1.intersection(v))
        if (nb>0):
            print(nb)
            acc[k] = nb/ (abs(len(v) - len(v1))+1)
            print(acc)
        if k not in acc.keys():
            acc[k] = 0
```

Is there a more efficient solution than this?

Comment: @DeepSpace sorry, there was a mistake in my example, for 1 it is 0.5 because it only has 1 out of 2 elements correct whereas for 3 it has 1 out of 3 correct.

Comment: can we assume `d1` and `d2` will always contain the same keys?

Comment: Yes d1 and d2 have the same keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we operate under the assumption that both dicts will have the same keys, this can be done with a dict comprehension with a single loop:

```
print({k1: (len(v1.intersection(d2[k1])) / (abs(len(v1) - len(d2[k1])) + 1))
       for k1, v1 in d1.items()})
```

outputs

```
{1: 0.5, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.3333333333333333}
```

This can be generalized a bit by making sure we take into account only the common keys between the two dicts, just to be on the safe side.

```
print({common_key: (len(d1[common_key].intersection(d2[common_key])) / (abs(len(d1[common_key]) - len(d2[common_key])) + 1))
       for common_key in d1.keys() & d2.keys()})
```

Comment: This is great, but there's an issue in cases like this: d1 = {1: {'hello', 'goodbye'}, 2:{'sayonnara'}, 3:{'origami','cat'}}
d2 = {1: {'goodbye'}, 2:{'hola', 'bye'}, 3:{'bird','origami'}} it will output 1 for 3 instead of 0.5

Comment: @ATidedHumour your code outputs the same for that example :)

Comment: you're right, I think I know what to do, thank you for your help, I'm accepting this answer.